# Using Chrome OS keyboard shortcuts with a plain 3rd party keyboard? Overview mode?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os

So I'm using a regular USB 3rd party keyboard with a chrome OS device in a desktop setup. I want to be able to access all the same features of chrome OS, but some are seemingly not available.

Specifically, overview mode. Accessing it has been described as
`Overview mode can be achieved by either a 3-finger swipe up or down on your trackpad or by hitting the overview button on the top row of your Chromebook keyboard`... But since I'm not using it in tablet or laptop mode, with a 3rd party keyboard -there is seemingly no way to access this feature. No hardware key and no UI icon. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL/DR; F5 on your external keyboard invokes ChromeOS' overview mode**

Example: I'm using a Logitech K400+ which has a row of F-keys that double as action keys (F1=back, F2=home, F3=window-switch, F4=right-click, F5=search, etc).  None of those keys map to ChromOS's overview mode, unfortunately but ChromeOS recognizes F5 as "Overview Mode".  With my setup, if I hit the F5 key, it invokes ChromeOS' search function, however if I press the "fn" modifier and then press F5 key, it sends F5 to ChromeOS which invokes Overview Mode.